# SQLcl history (up-arrow) rewrites my queries

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqlcl

Version

```
sql -version
SQLcl: Release 18.4.0.0 Production
```

I type this:

```
SQL>  exec dbaspace.long_ops;

SID  % Done  Start Time          Rem [s] Elapsed Message
==== ======= =================== ======= ======= ======================================================================================

There are currently no long running operations.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I press ARROW UP key to get the last command and SQLcl modifies my history like this:

```
SQL> BEGIN dbaspace.long_ops; END;;

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
BEGIN dbss.long_ops; END;;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 26:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";"
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

The rewritten history command does not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, I see that, it's a bug. Will log it and we can hope for a fix in version 19.4.

Just a quick note, you're missing out on features available in versions 19.1, 19.2, and soon to be version 19.3.